# Extracting Links not starting with "pic." using regex

Tags: python, regex, url

Like the title already states I am searching a regex expression which finds all the links on a website which do not start with "pic.".

**So far I have tried:**

```
((?!(pic))[\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.[\w\-_]+)+))([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

Comment: What do sample input data look like? Which are valid and to extract and which are not?

Comment: Basically just webinput with lots of urls. Like pic.url.com hello.wenew.de etc. @stribizhev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
(?<!\.)\b(?!pic\.)[\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.(?!pic\.)[\w\-_]+)+)(?:[\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aY1dE0/1)) which will not allow links like:

> pic.example.com
>
> www.pic.example.com

or:

```
(?<!\.)\b(?!pic\.?)[\w\-_]+(?:(?:\.(?!pic\.?)[\w\-_]+)+)(?:[\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?
```

([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/aY1dE0/2)) with additional `?` after `pic\.` which will also exclude:

> picexample.com
>
> www.picexample.com

I assume that rest of regex meets your needs